# Py2exe and PyGTK Entry Point Not Found

Tags: python, dll, gtk, pygtk, py2exe

i have created a pygtk example from  http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK and when i start the .exe file it geves me an error message:

`The procedure entry point gdk_win32_window_get_impl_hwnd could not be located in the dynamic link library libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll.`

the app is then running, but it is a ugly errmsg.
Can you tell me what is the problem?

Im using gtk2-runtime-2.24.8-2011-12-03-ash, py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7, pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.1.win32-py2.7, python-2.7.2.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing the pygtk-all-in-one installer and gtk2-runtime. You only need one of them not both.
The problem probably comes from loading the win32 theme, it'll work fine but look ugly.

The solution is to stop using gtk2-runtime.

Comment: OK I have done it. you just must replace the `libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll` in the `dist/` dir with the `dist/lib/libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll` :) it hase no error and looks OK.